# Paredit: How to just enter " or )

Tags: paredit

I am having enormous difficulties typing lisp code in Portacle, is a complete IDE for Common Lisp based on Emacs. It is trying to get cute whenever I enter a " or a ). Sometimes it breaks my code.

Scenario 1.

I had the following in the clipboard.

```
(substitute-in-file-name "${SystemDrive}/opt
```

I pasted this at the end of a line that already had the following text.

```
((file-directory-p
```

The result was the following line of text.

```
((file-directory-p (substitute-in-file-name "${SystemDrive}/opt
```

I then typed a " at the end of this line.

Portacle escaped the " so that the final result was as follows.

```
((file-directory-p (substitute-in-file-name "${SystemDrive}/opt\"
```

Portacle does similar nonsense when I try to type ).

How do I get " to simply put a " where my caret is instead of getting cute.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with paredit, but I think that C-q " and C-q ) should do what you want. C-q runs the command quoted-insert and reads the next character and itputs it as it is.

Comment: Is this a question about portacle or about emacs?

Comment: It looks like Portacle is a software bundle that includes Emacs and some packages. Not clear how they've configured it or how far from standard it is.

Comment: Regardless of `Portacle`, I can't find another post dealing with typing individual open or close parens, This is useful especially when  yanking  code from a region that was mistakenly short of an open or close parentheses... I think @andrej should post his comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C-q` runs the command `quoted-insert` and reads the next character and itputs it as it is (works everywhere on my emacs configuration). So I think that `C-q "` and `C-q )` should do what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately, Portacle remaps C-q to er/expand-region. I was able to run quoted-insert by using M-x quoted-insert and this did solve my problem. I think I am going to have to abandon Portacle as an unusable mess and go back to plain Emacs.